# syncfusion Xamarin error

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, syncfusion

Getting this error on main activity page...
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type Syncfusion.RangeNavigator.XForms.Droid.RangeNavigatorEventDependencyService while decoding custom attribute: (null)

just trying to implement a sfchart, haven't even gotten past the getting started and already getting an error.

here is my main activity code

```
using System;


using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.Droid;

namespace Drip.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Drip.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            new SfChartRenderer();

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my xaml code

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Drip.MyPage" xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms">
    <ContentPage.Content>
   <chart:SfChart x:Name="Chart">

    <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
  <chart:CategoryAxis LabelRotationAngle= "-45">
    <chart:CategoryAxis.Title>
      <chart:ChartAxisTitle Text="Meetup Date"/>
    </chart:CategoryAxis.Title>
  </chart:CategoryAxis>
</chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

    <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
  <chart:NumericalAxis>
    <chart:NumericalAxis.Title>
      <chart:ChartAxisTitle Text="Count"/>
    </chart:NumericalAxis.Title>
  </chart:NumericalAxis>
</chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
</chart:SfChart>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the xamarin forms version of chart control.  Make sure you add a reference to the following dlls in the android project

Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.Android.dll

Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.dll

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/introduction/control-dependencies#sfchart

Comment: I have done that. Not sure if ive done it correctly though. Im on visual studio community on the mac. I right click on references and edit reference then net assemblies and browse for the files necessary and hit ok

Comment: are you using any other syncfusion controls in the project?

Comment: I attempted to use the data grid control however couldnt get it to work aswell so just made my own custom list view.

Comment: ok are you sure you removed all the datagrid control references?

Comment: Should i have done so? You cant use 2 controls in one app?

Comment: How would you remove them?

Comment: delete the reference.   Yes you can use more than one control but if you are not using it I would remove the reference.   You can delete the reference by expanding references in the solution explorer. right click on the reference and select delete.

Comment: I have an older sfchart demo I did a while ago that also has a reference to Syncfusion.SfChart.Android.dll   https://github.com/vb2ae/syncfusionchartdemo

Answer (score 0):

We kindly request you to rebuild and run your application to resolve this.